# How to send XMLHttpRequest to specific php function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I am trying to do a image uploading with ajax. I have run into a bit of problem. I have two functions in func-ajax.php : function doSth(){} and function doSthElse(){}. I want to target the doSth() function
This is my javascript side:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'func-ajax.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);                  
xhr.send(file);
```

How can I specify whick function to send the request?

Comment: I do highly recommend implementing any number of solutions posted below, so I can reach different functions on back-end by simply tampering your javascript. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a specific function from the `func-ajax.php` file.

What you should do is create something like `ajax-controller.php`, containing

```
    $functionName = $_POST["func"]; // func parameter should be sent in AJAX, determines which function to run

    if (function_exists($functionName)) { // check if function exists
         $functionName(); // run function
    }
```

And send all requests from JS to this file `xhr.open("POST", 'ajax-controller.php', true);`

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send GET/POST parameters along with your request, and catch those in the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an HTTP request to a function.

You make a request for a resource. That request can include POST data and it can include HTTP headers.

The server then decides how to respond the request. It might choose to run a PHP program.

It is up to the PHP program to look at the requested resource / POST data / headers and determine which function(s) to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter in the data being sent and that you check for in some sort of if block that you call the function manually from. You could also introduce a framework like Slim, to create an REST-api point that you can hit.